# Understanding Methods Chaining in Javascript

Tags: javascript, chaining

I'm new to ES6 and Javascript and I can't figure out what's wrong with chaining this dump() method in the following piece of code.

It returns "**main.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dump' of undefined**":

```
class TaskCollection {

constructor(tasks = []) {
    this.tasks = tasks;
}

addTasks(newTasks = []) {
    this.tasks = this.tasks.concat(newTasks);
}

dump() {
    console.log(this.tasks);
}

}

let myTasks = new TaskCollection([
        'Do stuff'
]);

myTasks.addTasks([
    'New Task'
]).dump();
```

Now if I don't chain that dump() method, everything would work just fine.

```
myTasks.addTasks([
'New Task'
]);

myTasks.dump();
```

Comment: You need to `return this` from your `addTasks()` method. Otherwise, it returns `undefined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method `addTasks` is not returning a reference to the object. If you want chaining to work, your method needs to look like this:

```
addTasks(newTasks = []) {
    this.tasks = this.tasks.concat(newTasks);

    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to use method chaining, you need to return `this` from the earlier method. In your case, you don't return `this` from `addTasks`, so the result of calling `addTasks` is `undefined`, and you can't call methods on `undefined.`

So just add

```
return this;
```

...to any method you want to be able to chain from.

Method chaining is not something special. When you do:

```
addTasks(/*...*/).dump();
```

what you're doing is effectively:

```
var x = addTasks(/*...*/);
x.dump();
```

...just without the variable. Depending on how `addTasks` is written, you might be calling `dump` on the same object (method chaining) or on some other object entirely (if `addTasks` returned something other than `this`).

Answer (score 2):

```
You should return this in *addTasks* method
```

```js
    class TaskCollection {
        
        constructor(tasks = []) {
            this.tasks = tasks;
        }
        
        addTasks(newTasks = []) {
            this.tasks = this.tasks.concat(newTasks);
            return this;
        }
        
        dump() {
            console.log(this.tasks);
        }
        
        }
        
        let myTasks = new TaskCollection([
                'Do stuff'
        ]);
        
        myTasks.addTasks([
            'New Task'
        ]).dump();
```